# how to perform addition of column values in mySql?

Tags: mysql

I have one table named **tripdetails**:

**table structure:**

```
**trip no**    **invoice no**   **total balance**
111              1               500
111              2               800
```

i want to add these two invoices **total balance**...means 500+800=1300....

Comment: It seems you are looking for SQL's `SUM`.

Comment: you want to `sum` it ? where you want to add ? in table ?

Comment: yes, i want to add in table..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT trip_no,SUM(total_balance) as total 
FROM tripdetails 
WHERE trip_no = 111 
GROUP BY trip_no;
```

This should do it. It selects both rows with trip_no 111, then groups them and selects the sum of balances.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(total_balance) as invoice_total FROM tripdetails
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to use aggregate functions to do sum of a column.There is a pre-defined function which helps to obtain your desired output.

Syntax :

```
select sum(column_name) as alias 
from table_name
```